# rails application_controller using before_action is not processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I wan't to use the before_action in application_controller.rb 
and then some skip_before_actions ...

bit the defined function is not called ...

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  layout "application"

  before_action :user_logged_in, :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
     I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  # Prüft ob ein Nutzer eingeloggt ist.
  def user_logged_in

    puts "HA"

   if session[:user_id].nil?
     flash[:error] = "error"
      redirect_to :controller => :startsites, :action => :index
   else
      flash[:error] = "ok"
      redirect_to :controller => :startsites, :action => :index
   end

  end
end
```

The puts "HA" in user_logged_in is not shown ...

and in some controllers I tried to use this:

```
class MoviesController < ActionController::Base
   skip_before_action :user_logged_in, only: [:index, :show]
```

also not working ... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you looking for the `puts`? If you were to call the `Rails logger` instead, it would work.

Try to insert a `binding.pry` instead of the puts and see what happens (you obviously need to have [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) installed on your machine)